# Accessing index # of an array of structures in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, struct

I can't figure out if this is even possible in Swift, but using a for index loop I'm trying to match the index of my array with a property located within a structure within myarray

Data:

```
class MyClass {

struct myStruct {
    var name: String? = ""
    var age: Double = 0
}

let myArray: [myStruct] = [
    myStruct(name: "Gary", age: 35),
    myStruct(name: "Carol", age: 60),
    myStruct(name: "Lou", age: 55)
    ]
}
```

Controller:

```
var instanceofMyClass = MyClass()

for (index, age) in enumerate(instanceofMyClass.myArray) {
    println("my index is \(index) and age is \(age)")
```

When I substitute my array of structs with a simple array of strings, I return a value, but cannot return a value when it's an array of structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though your loop variables are named `(index, age)`, you're still iterating through `myArray`, and that contains instances of the struct you've defined. As a result `age` actually contains instances of that struct instead of doubles.

You need something like this to get the `age` values in a loop:

```
for (index, myStruct) in enumerate(instanceofMyClass.myArray) {
    println("my index is \(index) and age is \(myStruct.age)")
}
```